# JavaScript: Stringify actual variable name

Tags: javascript

I'm currently running a series of functions where the first argument is a variable defined elsewhere, and the second argument is a string that happens to be identical to the variable name:

```
assignString(Hello, 'Hello')
assignString(World, 'World')
assignString(Foo, 'Foo')
assignString(Bar, 'Bar')
...
```

Ideally I would like to simplify this to something like this:

```
['Hello', 'World', 'Foo', 'Bar'].forEach(() => { assignString... })

or

[Hello, World, Foo, Bar].forEach(() => { assignString... })
```

Is this actually possible?

Comment: It'd help if you'd post the code for `assignString()` and explain why it is you need to do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const vars = { Hello, World, Foo, Bar };
Object.keys(vars).forEach(key => assignString(vars[key], key));
```

Comment: Without seeing `assignString()` it's pretty hard to know how/if this would work.

Comment: @Pointy why do you think?

Comment: Well, the OP is not consistent in terms of the implications about how that function works.

Comment: @Pointy can you give me an example of `assignString` function where this does not work? (according to OP question)

Comment: I have really no idea what the OP is talking about; it could do a thousand possible things. I don't know whether those identifiers ("Hello") etc are local variables or global or what. That's my point: your answer *might* be correct, but it might not be even close.

Comment: @madox2 you were able to solve exactly my use case. @Pointy I really don't see where madox's answer would not work, regardless of the context. The variables `Hello, World, etc.`, whether local or not, will obviously be accessible to `assignString` in this scenario and I assumed that was obvious.

Comment: I specifically wanted to avoid providing more context as the situation is rather complex (and would not help in answering my question). Nonetheless, to give you an explanation the `assignString` function is actually something called `modalifyComponent(ModalComponent, refName)` that takes in a React Modal View component and is assigned a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) value, which I thought would make sense to name according to its component. The purpose of this function is to make all modals accessible for opening and closing using its refs.

Comment: @robinnnnn the reason it's good (for people *answering* and for *you*) to include context and explanation of goals and choices is that it provides for the possibility that somebody will be able to give you guidance you haven't anticipated or imagined. Without that, all you get is a specific direct answer to a limited question. It might be useful in a narrow sense, but you'll never know if something vastly more helpful to your overall project was missed.

Comment: can you include assignString - seriously how is this helpful for everyone else?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could dynamically create variables based on a string value is by doing something like this:

```
var exampleStringValue = 'HELLO';
window[exampleStringValue] = exampleStringValue;
console.log(window.HELLO);

// or, since window is the global context in the browser
console.log(HELLO)
```

I honestly can't say I can dream up a use-case where that's a good practice, but I don't know your use-case, so no judgement here :)

I'd also like to point out this little library that I've found useful for creating objects where the keys have same value as the name of the key: https://github.com/STRML/keyMirror.  I've found that to be used pretty heavily in the React community.

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable name and the string are **equivalent**, there's no need to pass it in twice. I'd rather pass in the scope of the variable. You could do this so it works in whatever scope you're in:

```
function assignString(scope, val){
    scope[val] = val;
}
```

Called like

```
assignString(window, "Hello");
```

Output of `console.log(Hello)  ==> "Hello"`

Answer (score -1):

Using the new ES6 Map object, we can create name/value pairs in a structure that can then be turned into an Array, so forEach can work:

```
  // Variables that assignString will need:
  var Hello = "var1", World = "var2", Foo = "var3", Bar = "var4";

  // Map object that contains name of variables and strings that match variable name
  var m = new Map([[Hello, "Hello"],[World,"World"],[Foo, "Foo"], [Bar, "Bar"]]);

  // Turn Map into Array so forEach will work:
  var a = Array.from(m);

  // Call forEach which calls assingString and passes key name
  // (variable name) and string value
  a.forEach((value) =>  { assignString(value[0], value[1]); });
```

See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/qnwsajes/34/

Comment: @Juhana Please consider removing your comments and up voting (if it was you that down voted) as I have re vamped my solution to match the scenario.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an object with your data, iterate over the keys, and pass the key-value-pair to your assignString function.

```
var data = {
    Hello: Hello,
    World: World,
    Foo: Foo,
    Bar: Bar
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => assignString(data[key], key));
```

Comment: This code's execution would be ended up with `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment(…)`